# Initialize divs with starting-width in a display: flex

Tags: css

I am struggling with achieving a particular layout. I have a row that spans the width of the screen and inside of it many inline divs (tabs).

I would like all the tabs to start at the same size (say 200px), but then adjust to fit the screen when we have too many of them. With `display: flex`, we can achieve the fitting (see code below), but I am unsure how to initialize the width of each tab to be the same.

TLDR: How do I make all tabs start with the same size and then shrink proportionally as they need to fit the screen?

```js
function newItem() {
  var newTab = document.createElement('div')
  newTab.classList.add('tab')
  newTab.innerHTML = 'Hello'
  document.querySelector('.container').appendChild(newTab)
}
```

```css
body, html {
    width: 100%
}
    
.container {
    display: flex;
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
}

.tab {
    display: inline;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 1px;
    max-width: 200px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <button onclick="newItem()">New</button>
    <div class="tab">One</div>
    <div class="tab">Two</div>
    <div class="tab">Twenty Three</div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force children to *"fill parent evenly"* by giving them all an identical `flex` value.

In this case, you can simply apply `flex: 1` to the `.tab` definition.

```js
function newItem() {
  var newTab = document.createElement('div')
  newTab.classList.add('tab')
  newTab.innerHTML = 'Hello'
  document.querySelector('.container').appendChild(newTab)
}
```

```css
body, html {
    width: 100%
}
    
.container {
    display: flex;
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
}

.tab {
    display: inline;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 1px;
    max-width: 200px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <button onclick="newItem()">New</button>
    <div class="tab">One</div>
    <div class="tab">Two</div>
    <div class="tab">Twenty Three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, wow, that was super easy. Works, thank you! One more thing: how do I ensure that the elements do not exceed the line now? If I add a bit of padding to the tabs, they no longer shrink once they reach the size of the padding.

Comment: @AndreiCioara Hmm, unfortunately I'm not all that sure you can apply dynamic (shrinking) padding to compensate for that many items :( At least not that I can think of immediately. I can play around with it tomorrow though.